# Wordpress admin categories sort show is wrong

Tags: wordpress

I create categories like:

```
A
-- A1
-- A2
---- A21
---- A22
-- A3
B
-- B1
-- B2
C
```

But in new post on left side admin show wrong:

```
A
-- A1
---- A21
---- A22
B
-- B2
C
A2
A3
B1
```

Why? How I can fix it?

Comment: You mean in the frontend side ?

Comment: @TejasGajjar yes, in wp-admin when I want send new post or edit old post